# Should I put my operating system or my working files on the faster hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, computer-building

I'm a video editor working with large HD files. I am building a new computer and need some help. I will be running 2 hard drives. One with the operating system and all the programs. And one with all the project files I will be working from. I am keeping these seperate. I will be purchasing a 10k rpm hard drive. So i will have a 10k rpm drive, and a 7200rpm drive. Should I put the OS on the faster drive, or put my working files on the faster drive?

Comment: Are both drives similar in size? Cause otherwise this could be a practical factor to consider too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are concerned that you might not have enough RAM so will regularly be swapping to disk, I would suggest putting the project work on the faster drive. I expect you will notice a difference when working on large files with processes that are not CPU-bound. You are going to be reading/writing to your working media files a lot more than you will be requiring the machine to read program files (and related data) and write to log files on the system drive.

Also, use what space you have spare on the other drive for local backups, unless you already have such a backup arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, and you have the cash, would it be feasible to install the operating system onto SSD drive, use that for your scratch drive and operating system and the files you are currently editing, then use the large drive for backup and storage.

Answer (score 0):

Put your OS on the faster drive; as 7200RPM and 10kRPM isn't that much of a difference. **With all honesty you're being anal here about speed you wont even be able to notice.**

Also if the 10k is external then you're going to be wasting performance.